# Collatz conjecture for numbers of th form $2^n +1$

Tags: co.combinatorics, collatz-conjecture

Everybody has heard of the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and it is a nice programming exercise to write a function, that calculates for a given number $n$ the number of iterations it takes until one reaches $1$. However if one restricts to numbers of the form $2^n+1$ one gets the following sequence of integers (NO matches in [oeis](http://oeis.org/)). It starts with

7,5,19,12,26,27,121,122,35,36,156,113,52,53,98,99,100,101,102,
72,166,167,168,169,170,171,247,173,187,188,251,252,178,179,317,
243,195,196,153,154,155,156,400,326,495,496,161,162,331,332,408,
471,410,411,337,338,339,340,553,479,480,481,482,483,559,560,561,
562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,626,
578,628,629,630,631,583,584,634,635,636,637,894,895,640,641,898,643

"Usually" it grows by $1$ and at some positions it takes a completely different value. Then sometimes it jumps back as if there was never a different value involved (like 575,576,626,578) This seemed to me a bit strange/interesting and funny.It there anything known about this special sequence. Maybe there is a characterization of those positions, where this sequence grows by $1$. I am not sure, how to make a well posed question out of this.

EDIT: and there is the same behavior for numbers of the form $2^n-1$

Comment: I'm sorry -- I feel a little stupid -- but I am not understanding this. Let me ask a dumb question: why does this start with 7, and why is 5 the next number? 

Comment: Because starting with 3 takes 7 steps to get to 1, and starting with 5 takes 5 steps.

Comment: After $4 k= 4*\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ steps, you end up with either $3^k+1$ or $2*3^k +1$, with the former if $n$ is even and the latter if $n$ is odd. There seem to be some interesting relations between Collatz sequences of these numbers, but I'm not an expert at all, so I know nothing of research done in this field.
Same holds for $2^n -1$, ends up at $3^k-1$ or $2*3^k -1$ after same $k$ steps.

Comment: The sequence has been submitted to OEIS (not yet approved) with links here.

Comment: If you plot the numbers, some interesting patterns emerge (mostly increasing but with scattered outliers, and longer and longer incremental sequences). A very different pattern from the usual Collatz 'number of steps' function A006577.

Comment: Henrik, your question has produced a new sequence on oeis :-) http://oeis.org/A179118

Comment: have worked on collatz problem with some writeup [here](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/code/collatz-conjecture-experiments/) incl an exercise vaguely similar, looking at iterates mod 2^n. the number of iterations to reach 1 is sometimes called "stopping time" eg as on the wikipedia pg...

Comment: I've added more terms to the above sequence. Interestingly there are many long runs of terms that increase by 1.

Comment: Recently a similar Q. occured in MSE on which I composed an answer, showing some interesting heuristics, maybe showing properties with some significance. If this is of interest https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/MSE240109_comment.htm I could convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can find some closed formulas resembling your problem in

- Andrei, Ş., Kudlek, M., Niculescu, R.Ş.: [Some results on the Collatz problem.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002360000039) Acta Informatica Vol. 37, No. 2, pp. 145–160 (2000). [Zbl 1003.11005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1003.11005)

Hope it helps.

EDIT: (To complement the answer) You should also check the references in the
section I.8 "Consecutive numbers with the same height" in

- Günther J. Wirsching, [The Dynamical System Generated by the $3n+1$ Function.](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0095987) Lec. Notes in Mathematics v. 1681. Berlin: Springer (1998). [Zbl 0892.11002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0892.11002)

There you'll find that there is an infinite number of very long sequences of consecutive numbers for which your Collatz function is constant, which is
also very interesting.